# How to slide a banner using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slider

code:

```
<script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
</script>

<div class="slideshow-container">
    <?php
        if(empty($banner))
        {
            echo $this->session->flashdata('error');
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($banner as $ban)
            {
    ?>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>product/<?php echo $ban['category']; ?>">
                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/banner/<?php echo $ban['banner']; ?>" style="width:100%">
                    </div>
                </a>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

In this code I am creating banner slider section where images are showing dynamically perfect but images are not sliding automatically one by one. So, How can I slide images one by one? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't see any element with class **dot**. Removing references to those you can simply add a [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) callback.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    //dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

showSlides(slideIndex);
setInterval(function() {
    plusSlides(1);
}, 300);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="slideshow-container">
    <a href="">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=1">
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=2">
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=3">
        </div>
    </a>
    <br/>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

- Use `itv = setInterval(callback, timing)` to *autoplay* the slideshow
- Use `clearInterval(itv)` on `'mouseenter'` Event.
- Don't use inline STYLE and JS like `onclick=""`
- Don't limit yourself on the number of slideshows per-page

Here's a slightly modified example:

```js
!(function() {

  const slideshow = EL => {
  
    const ELS_prevNext = EL.querySelectorAll('.prev, .next');
    const ELS_slide = EL.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    const t = ELS_slide.length;
    let c = 0;
    let itv = null;
    
    const slide = () => {
      c = c<0 ? t-1 : c%t;
      ELS_slide.forEach(EL => EL.classList.remove('is-active'));
      ELS_slide[c].classList.add('is-active');
    };
    
    const play = () => itv = setInterval(() => {++c, slide()}, 3000);
    const stop = () => clearInterval(itv);
    
    ELS_prevNext.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener('click', ev => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      c = (ev.currentTarget.classList.contains('next') ? ++c : --c);
      slide();
    }));
    
    EL.addEventListener('mouseenter', stop);
    EL.addEventListener('mouseleave', play);
    play(); // Start slideshow!!!
  };
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.slideshow').forEach(slideshow);
  
}());
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.slideshow .slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0.4s, visibility 0.4s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slideshow .slide.is-active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.slideshow .slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slideshow .prev,
.slideshow .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #fff;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.slideshow .prev {
  right: auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>SLIDESHOW AUTOPLAY AND PAUSE ON HOVER</h2>

<div class="slideshow">
  <a href="#!">
    <div class="slide is-active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x600/0bf?text=1">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#!">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x600/f0b?text=2">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#!">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x600/bf0?text=3">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<h2>AS MANY SLIDESHOWS AS YOU WANT</h2>

<div class="slideshow">
  <a href="#!">
    <div class="slide is-active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x600/fb0?text=A">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#!">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x600/0fb?text=B">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#!">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x600/b0f?text=C">
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```